# Do I have to change the chaincase lubricant when adjusting the clutch during routine maintenance? 2015 HD Road King

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, clutch, chain, harley-davidson

I am completely new to motorcycle maintenance, but **need to adjust my clutch**.  I have watched a [demonstration video](https://youtu.be/ZOo17nIiYhM) for a similar model (I think) - but couldn't find an exact match.

Since I will be adjusting the cable (removing it from the fastener, opening the derby/clutch cover, etc...), **will chaincase lubricant spill out of the derby cover when I go to adjust the clutch tension?**

The owner manual's service chart does not indicate that the chaincase lubricant needs to be changed.  Any other special concerns other than spilling lubricant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following answer to my question after digging more on YouTube, thanks to [J&P Cycles](http://www.jpcycles.com/) and this video https://youtu.be/4p_vjd0GtCk

**Clutch adjustment must be done with the bike upright or the primary lubricant will spill** out of the derby cover.  According to the video, this applies to all late model "big-twin" bikes back to the EVO.

While it isn't required while adjusting the clutch, one can change the primary lubricant anyway (since the case is open) - especially if you are adjusting the clutch because of clutch wear (there will be more debris in the oil).

From owner's manual to the majority of tutorial videos, **most sources recommend changing the derby seal at this time as well**.  My Harley Dealership sold a package of common o-rings and seals which included one for the derby cover.